# Bulk revert to previous Default Program settings

Tags: windows-7

I managed to set my default program for all extensions to Chrome and am struggling to revert this. eg it won't let me open Skype as it tries to open it in Chrome. Only affects one user.

I have changed the computer defaults on another user/admin and it didn't apply after restart.

Can anyone help me disable this default so that files open in the correct program?

Comment: System Restore perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

The simple, but laborious route would be change the programs here in Control Panel

```
Control Panel\Programs\Default Programs\Set Associations
```

A more ambitious, but risky strategy would would be to export the registry settings from another machine and import to your machine.  (Naturally backup at least the registry on your machine before you attempt).

These file associations are stored in this part of registry.

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes
```

The Import / Export operation is fairly transparent, Regedit, File Menu, Import or Export.

**Key point:** put the focus on the above registry location, before you export.

For perfection, you need a third old machine, or virtual machine to test the idea before you try on your machine.

Answer (score 0):

If **System Restore** doesn't help, you can restore default file associations for EXE and other common extensions using the .REG files available here:

- [Restore Default Windows 7 File Extension Type Associations](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/19449-default-file-type-associations-restore.html)
- [File Association Fixes for Windows 7](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/file-asso-fixes-for-windows-7)